# Making a Form appear above everything

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a stand-in Start Menu for Windows 8 and I've tried:

```
this.TopMost = true;
```

but it seems to only work until the form loses focus. Is there was an easy way to make the "start button" appear above the Task Bar permanently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raymond Chen talks about the problems with topmost windows [on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx).  I recommend checking that out.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: It's the right answer. There's no such thing as making a program appear above all other programs "permanently", just a lot of hacks and counter-hacks. Raymond Chen's post (or series of posts) is the best answer to why you shouldn't try to play that game.